# Unable to login to xmpp chat server when system firewall enabled

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I am developing a website with chat feature.One of system works well with chating. When i testing in other system which firewall enabled, the xmpp connection not able to setup.

Its not triggering CONNECT callback.If i disable the firewall then every thing is working fine. I am using Strophe.js plugin for chat feature in my website.

Anyone had faced this type of issue.How to resolve it..

Comment: Try to open appropriate ports in your firewall. In openfire's webpanel there is a port list with their descriptions. Refer to this list to determine which ports to open. Also refer to firewalls guide how to open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three options:

1) Open the port on your firewall to match with the HTTP-Bind port of your connection manager. Openfire's default port for HTTP-Binding is 7070, Punjab uses 5280.

2) Change your configuration to use a different port, one which is already open.

3) You might be able to setup a proxy on your web server to redirect the messages from Strophe to the BOSH connection manager.